# FindRoot doesn't find root

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, iteration

I am facing a problem that my FindRoot doesn't find the actual roots.

I am trying to make a loop that iterates my parameter sets (U0,X0,\Sigma0) to find sets that satisfy some conditions. Here is my pre-setup

```
P = 1;
C0 = 0;
eqold[\[CapitalSigma]_] = {Z'[s] == -Sin[\[Psi][s]], \[Psi]''[
     s] == -\[Psi]'[s]/X[s] Cos[\[Psi][s]] + 
     Cos[\[Psi][s]] Sin[\[Psi][s]]/X[s]^2 + \[Gamma][s]/
       X[s] Sin[\[Psi][s]] + P X[s]/2 Cos[\[Psi][s]], \[Gamma]'[
     s] == (\[Psi]'[s] - C0)^2/2 - Sin[\[Psi][s]]^2/(2 X[s]^2) + 
     P X[s] Sin[\[Psi][s]] + \[CapitalSigma], X'[s] == Cos[\[Psi][s]]};
help[eq_] := (Subtract @@ eq // Together // Numerator) == 0
\[Psi]1[U0_, X0_, \[CapitalSigma]0_] := Module[{soln, s1},
  soln = NDSolve[{eqold[\[CapitalSigma]0][[{1, 4}]], 
     help /@ eqold[\[CapitalSigma]0][[{2, 3}]], \[Psi][0] == 
      0, \[Psi]'[0] == U0, X[0] == 0, \[Gamma][0] == 0, 
     Z[0] == 0}, {X, \[Psi], Z, \[Gamma]}, {s, 0, 15}, 
    SolveDelayed -> True];
  s1 = s /. FindRoot[Evaluate[X[s] /. soln] == X0, {s, 2 \[Pi]}];
  {X[s1] /. soln, \[Psi][s1] /. soln}]
```

If you look at how s1 is defined inside the Module, X[s1] is set to be equal to X0. And by introducing another FindRoot as

```
FindRoot[\[Psi]1[a, 0.1, -1.1 P^(2/3)][[2]] == \[Pi], {a, 0.5}]
```

I want to find U0 that satisfy

```
X[s1] /. soln==X0,
\[Psi][s1] /. soln==\[Pi]
```

under the given parameter set (X0,\Simga0). So eventually, by varying X0 and \Sigma0, I get the whole sets of (U0,X0,\Sigma0) that satisfy the conditions above.

This works quite well for this specific \Sigma0=-1.1 value.

```
FindRoot[\[Psi]1[a, 0.1, -1.1 P^(2/3)][[2]] == \[Pi], {a,0.5}] // Quiet
\[Psi]1[a /. %, 0.1, -1.1 P^(2/3)]
```

gives

```
{a -> 0.448875}
{{0.1}, {3.14159}}
```

So the conditions are satisfied.

However, if I slightly vary \Sigma0, this doesn't work, and what FindRoot finds is not the roots anymore.

```
FindRoot[\[Psi]1[a, 0.1, -1.0 P^(2/3)][[2]] == \[Pi], {a,0.5}] // Quiet;
\[Psi]1[a /. %, 0.1, -1.0 P^(2/3)]
```

gives

```
{{0.1}, {6.23523}}
```

So \psi[s1] is not equal to \pi. I suspect this could be somehow relevant to the target value of a, but I highly suspect there will be a solution near 0.5 by some analysis.

Will there be a good way to let the code finds the actual roots? Or can someone recommend me a better way to form an iteration code that might be viable for my case?

Thank you

Comment: I guess it could be all the errors you ignore by applying `Quiet`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you for the comment. Then should I think that it works for certain parameter sets are just a bit of luck? Do you have some idea to make it work properly for arbitrary parameters?

Comment: Two suggestions.  Include the option `Evaluated -> False` in `FindRoot`.  And plot  `\[Psi]1[a, 0.1, -1.0 P^(2/3)][[2]] - Pi` to see what your function looks like.